# Pushed data object with SignalR is shallow

Tags: c#, angular, signalr

I have setup my application with SignalR where posted messages are pushed to all connected clients. So far so good. 
The `Message` object contains a complex property `Priority`.

```
public class Message {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public Priority MessagePriority { get; set; }
}

public class Priority {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SortIndex { get; set; }
}
```

The `Message` item pushed to the client is however a shallow copy which means the `Priority` property is `undefined` but other properties, `Id` and `Contents`, are correctly set.
How can I make sure that a deep copy is pushed to the client?

Comment: I don't know if it helps on your case, but I've been using JSON serialization to send complex objects through SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually caused by the fact that the client is unable to map certain properties because the propertynames were capitalized. By explicitly setting the names of the properties.

```
[Serializable]
public class Priority {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sortindex")]
    public int SortIndex { get; set; }
}
```